# Print fields a different node

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a News page which links to a bunch of news articles and I'm looking to print the header of the News Page on the individual articles.

The field_get_items doesn't return anything right now.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
if ($node->type == 'article') {
         $news_header = field_get_items('page', $node, 'group_header'); print_r($news_header);

             //$url = file_create_url($node->field_header_image['und'][0]['uri']);
             //echo '<img src="' . $url . '" width="100%">';   
            // }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading the node first? If you are not getting anything returned then it's probably because $node isn't set. Also is the 'News node' a node type of article?

I would start by trying to retrieve the node information first:

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
var_dump($node);
```

Also I think your field_get_items is not working as your entity type is 'page' but you are inside a check for a node type of article try:

```
$news_header = field_get_items('node', $node, 'group_header');
```

Comment: This is retrieving the information of the current node that I'm  in which is an article content type.  I need to retrieve a field - group_header from a different node which is content type page = news. thanks for you help on this!

Comment: Ok that makes sense does the article have the news page as a menu parent? Or is it in the irk path?

Comment: Here's an example of an article path: news/2015/12/09/article-name.  news is page that lists all the news articles.

Comment: It looks like you have no way of loading that node information while on the article, The easiest answer is to make a block as a header image for the articles.

What is the path of the hub page you want the header from? if it's 'news' you could work with that.